# AWK ignores case in character classes

Tags: awk

I would like to write an awk conditional that matches a string if it begins with a capital letter.  Here is a sample data file.

```
a
b
c
A
B
C
d
e
```

Let's say I want to match all lines that matches characters ABC.

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[ABC]/) print }' test 
A
B
C
```

Easy enough.  But this doesn't work if I use a character class.  Case is ignored.

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[A-C]/) print }' test 
b
c
A
B
C
```

Interestingly this works:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^[[:upper:]]/) print }' < test
A
B
C
```

From the documentation, I would expect the command to be:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^[:upper:]/) print }' < test
```

What am I misunderstanding?  Specifically, why is `[A-C]` case insensitive and why do I need to write `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[:upper:]`?

```
echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
```

Comment: I don't see your results. What does your `LANG` environment variable hold?

Comment: From the gawk man page:  A character class is only valid in  a  regular  expression  inside  the
       brackets  of a character list.

Comment: I may understand what you are saying.  I need `[[A-C]]`?  `awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^[[A-C]]/) print }' test` gives 0 results.  Same for gawk.

Comment: no.  suppose you want to search for a hex digit, you could say `/[[:digit:]a-fA-F]/` -- so the `[:character_class:]` is inside the outer `[brackets]` like plain characters

Comment: Gotcha, I was confused because sometimes `[A-C]` is referred to as a character class (i.e. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html and some versions of `man awk`) but not in `man gawk`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I misunderstanding?
>   Specifically, why is [A-C] case
>   insensitive

This probably has to do with your locale which could affect character class ranges.

Try setting `export LC_ALL=C` then running your `awk` command again with `[A-C]`

> why do I need to write [[:upper:]]
>   instead of [:upper:]?

`[:upper:]` is basically a locale insensitive way of writing the *range* `A-Z`, but you also want this to be a character class so you wrap it in `[]`, hence `[[:upper:]]`. So for example, if you wanted to match all upper case characters and digits you would write `[[:upper:][:digit:]]`

Comment: That makes fine sense (re: [:upper:]) but can you explain why `awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^[:upper:]/) print }' < test` returns just `e`??

Comment: Yes, it was a local issue.  `export LC_ALL=C` presented the expected output.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @schmid, this `[:upper:]` is exactly the same as this `[epru:]` -- brackets contain a set of characters you want to match.